# Como obter valor do botão ao disparar um evento shown.bs.modal

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3

Segue o código:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="meubotao"type="button" value="5">Click Me!</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#meubotao" ).click(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

Também tenho esse código a seguir (dispara esse evento após de modal a ser carregado):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // como obter valor a partir daqui...
})
```

O evento click ("meubotão"), posso obter valor utilizando `$(this).val();` ou exemplo de [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/1821/).

Como eu posso obter valor desse botão depois de modal a ser carregado ?

Comment: Já pensou em colocar este valor em uma variável? Assim você pode utilizar onde quiser.

Comment: Sim, já pensei nisso tbm, tem como obter valor direto do evento ?

Comment: Já tentou fazer `$('#meubotao').val()` após o evento shown do modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO HTML:**

Utilizamos o recurso data-* :

```
<button id="meubotao"type="button" data-value="5">Click Me!</button>
```

**NO SCRIPT:**

Precisamos resgatar o valor.

```
//Evento de disparo para quando modal é carregada.
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    //Selecionamos o botão que disparou o evento.
    var botao = $(event.relatedTarget);
    //Aqui você pega o valor.
    var valor = botao.data('value');

   //Faça o que quiser com o valor.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi direito:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // Aqui você pode fazer o que quiser com o valor
    $('#meubotao').val();
})
```

Comment: Já tentei, ele fica como `undefined`.

Comment: Esse modal carrega algum conteúdo externo à página do botão onde ele é chamado?